# array_search() throws error on second parameter

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am having a problem when looking for a specific keyword in an array. I am using Laravel.

I am trying to locate specific posts that have a specific keyword, exactly like the twitter function.

When visiting www.foobar.com/shoutouts/$hashtag the following function is executed:

```
public function shoutoutSpecific($hashtag) {
        $hashtag = '#' . $hashtag;
        $shoutouts = Shoutout::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

        foreach($shoutouts as $shoutout) {
          if (array_search($hashtag, $shoutout->hashtag) !== false) {
            $shoutouts2 = $shoutouts2 . $shoutout;
          }
        }

        return view('shoutout', compact('shoutouts2'));
    }
```

The database table for shoutout->hashtag contains example the following

```
a:1:{i:0;s:5:"#test";}
```

So when visiting www.foobar.com/shoutouts/test, the function should locate specific shoutouts that have a hashtag as #test and thereby throw these to an array which can be looped trough in a view.

However, when i visit www.foobar.com/shoutouts/test, i get

```
array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given
```

and i dont get this, because the second parameter is an array in  the database.

All help appreciated.

Comment: It's telling you what's wrong. You passed a string. `array_search()` searches values of an array for a given string.

Answer (score 0):

`a:1:{i:0;s:5:"#test";}` is serialized value of:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=> string(5) "#test"
}
```

So first you have to deserialize it using i.e. `unserialize($string)` function. After that `array_search` should work as expected.

Laravel can do this automatically by defining which properties you wish to be casted to json when accessed:

```
protected $casts = [
    'hashtag' => 'array'
];
```

More on that here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting